# migrate live process from one machine to the other

Tags: 14.04, process

I am going to work on a project in which one live process should migrate from one Ubuntu machine to the other machine( in a homogeneous environment ) so what are all the things I should know before this. Everything will going to be be implemented from scratch, so which programming language I should use ?

Comment: maybe you should provide a little more info about the process and the environment...

Answer (score 1):

The answer you are looking for is worthy of an entire specialized research team... the requirements for this are just too many. AskUbuntu may be the wrong place.

Things to take note of would include: process memory, thread states, memory held by the graphics card, open file descriptors, kernel socket (Internet/UNIX) states, other IPC channels, kernel states of any opened device files, memory maps, environment, the entire kernel-space memory in case the process was in the middle of a sys-call (such as when waiting for an action to happen), properties of the process' memory (such as no-execute bits), and many, MANY others (perhaps twice more than what I already listed).

Since most of these require kernel and device driver patches, the languages you need would be C and ASM.

A project attempting to do this is called LinuxPMI, you may want to look into it.

Alternative ways of migrating a process:

- Suspend-to-disk, and use an external system to copy the swap partition and the entire disk over to another system
- Host the process inside a virtual machine, and let its root filesystem be a union (i.e. UnionFS or AuFS) of a base read-only system image, and a blank image that will be filled with whatever changes the system makes; then suspend the virtual machine, and copy over the smaller image
- Implement (from scratch) an entire single-process virtual machine, that implements the full i686 instruction set and provides wrappers and hooks for every single system and library call needed